# El ID del componente formulario8:precioProducto ya se ha encontrado en la vista

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Glassfish me genera este error

```
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: El ID del componente formulario8:precioProducto ya se ha encontrado en la vista.
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:951)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:935)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:935)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:461)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:460)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./plantillaCliente.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="links">
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='../RecursosModulos/css/datatables/bootstrap.datatables.css'></link>
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='../RecursosModulos/css/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css'></link>  
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../RecursosModulos/css/sweetalert2.css"></link>
                <script src="../RecursosModulos/js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function myFunction1(cal, idform) {
                        x = cal.name;
                        document.getElementById("calificar" + idform + ":demo").value = x;

                    }

                    function deshabilitarBotonCalificar(pal) {
                        document.getElementById("calificar" + pal).disabled = "true";
                    }

                    function Calcular(temp, palabra) {
                        pcantidad = temp.value;
                        pvalor = document.getElementById("formulario" + palabra + ":precioProducto").value;
                        document.getElementById('precioPedido' + palabra).value = (pcantidad * pvalor);
                    }

                </script>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="tituloPag">
                <title>Mis pedidos | Effective Orders</title>
            </ui:define>
```

si me pudieran ayudar lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

El problema sucede porque tienes dos componentes JSF `<h:componente>` con el mismo ID dentro del mismo formulario `<h:form>`. Asegúrate de que tus componentes posean IDs diferentes y de que cuando los generes mediante `<c:forEach>` utilices alguna variable para cambiar el nombre de los componentes, o mejor aún: no utilices `<c:forEach>` en su lugar utiliza `<ui:repeat>`.